# Use database with execute is right way?

Tags: t-sql

Which will be the right way of using a database with `execute`?

**Method 1**:

```
declare @query nvarchar(max),  
        @db varchar(100) = 'figmdhqimanagementaad'  

set @query = 'select top 100 * from  [' + @db + '].dbo.tblencounter '  

execute Sp_ExecuteSQL @query
```

**Method 2**

```
Execute('use ' + @db + 'select top 100 * from tblencounter')
```

Comment: I dont know which one is the best, but i know what i would use mostly, and that is the first statement :) But it can depend on what my SQL is built around.

Comment: Umm I don't think, in the example you provided, it matters.  There's advantages and disadvantages to both.  Best in terms of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say there is a right and wrong way in this case. It's Dynamic SQL and you have mitigated some SQL injection buy using brackets. I would use QUOTENAME on the second version.

```
declare @query nvarchar(max)
declare @db varchar(100) = 'figmdhqimanagementaad'  

set @query = 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@db) + ' select top 100 * from tblencounter'

print(@query)
```

But beware, even this is subject to SQL injection if someone knows the DB name. You have mitigated this by making it only a `varchar(100)` though. You could always check to make sure the database exists too.

```
declare @query nvarchar(max)
declare @db varchar(100) = 'figmdhqimanagementaad'  

if exists(select * from sys.databases where name = @db)
begin
    set @query = 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@db) + ' select top 100 * from tblencounter'

    print(@query)
end
```